# Formatting JSON Response in .NET Core 2.1. Move multiple properties to single enum property

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi

I'd like to format my JSON response from this (Sensitive data removed):

```
{
    "id": 252,
    "name": "PRODUCT NAME",
    "manufacturer": "PRODUCT MANUFACTURER",
    "sku": "PRODUCT SKU",
    "ean": "PRODUCT EAN",
    "departmentID": 42,
    "department": "DEPARTMENT NAME",
    "categoryID": 178,
    "category": "CATEGORY NAME",
    "price": 0.00,
    "msrp": 0.00,
    "inactive": true,
    "stock": 0,
    "weight": 0,
    "imgFull": "IMAGE URL",
    "extendedDescription": "PRODUCT DESCRIPTION"
}
```

To this (Department and Category moved to 2nd dimension):

```
{
    "id": 252,
    "name": "PRODUCT NAME",
    "manufacturer": "PRODUCT MANUFACTURER",
    "sku": "PRODUCT SKU",
    "ean": "PRODUCT EAN",
    "Department": {
        "departmentID": 42,
        "department": "DEPARTMENT NAME"
    },
    "Category": {
        "categoryID": 178,
        "category": "CATEGORY NAME",
    },
    "price": 0.00,
    "msrp": 0.00,
    "inactive": true,
    "stock": 0,
    "weight": 0,
    "imgFull": "IMAGE URL",
    "extendedDescription": "PRODUCT DESCRIPTION"
}
```

This is not only to make the response neater, but I would like to use the method to add additional properties.  For example, for products with multiple images I'd like to include all the links rather than just the main link.

The product class is this:

```
public class apiProducts
{
    [Key]
    public Int32 Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public String Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public String Manufacturer { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public String SKU { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public String EAN { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Int32 DepartmentID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public String Department { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Int32 CategoryID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public String Category { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Decimal Price { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Decimal MSRP { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Boolean Inactive { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Int32 Stock { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Double Weight { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public String ImgFull { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public String ExtendedDescription { get; set; }
}
```

By my limited understanding of .NET Core the JSON object is formatted directly from the class, so I'm not sure how to make the class push multiple properties into an Enum to format it as requested.  This is probably straight forward (I hope) but I don't know what search term to use to find the answer :( I apologise if this has been answered already elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was straight forward enough.  First I need objects for the new category/department fields:

```
public class apiProductDepartments
{
    [Key]
    public Int32 ID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public String Name { get; set; }
}
public class apiProductCategories
{
    [Key]
    public Int32 ID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public String Name { get; set; }
}
```

We add those to the main product class, and add the Annotation `[IgnoreDataMember]` to the original `DepartmentID` & `DepartmentName` properties (same for `CategoryID` & `CategoryName`) from the `System.Runtime.Serialization` namespace to remove them from the json response (We don't need the properties twice so this will get rid of them from the json):

```
public class apiProducts
{
    [Key]
    public Int32 Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public String Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public String Manufacturer { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public String SKU { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public String EAN { get; set; }
    public apiProductDepartments Department { get; set; }
    [IgnoreDataMember]
    [Required]
    public Int32 DepartmentID { get; set; }
    [IgnoreDataMember]
    [Required]
    public String DepartmentName { get; set; }
    public apiProductCategories Category { get; set; }
    [IgnoreDataMember]
    [Required]
    public Int32 CategoryID { get; set; }
    [IgnoreDataMember]
    [Required]
    public String CategoryName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Decimal Price { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Decimal MSRP { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Boolean Inactive { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Int32 Stock { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Double Weight { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public String ImgFull { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public String ExtendedDescription { get; set; }
}
```

Then we just populate the property by using the existing properties:

```
foreach(apiProducts p in results)
            {
                apiProductDepartments dept = new apiProductDepartments();
                apiProductCategories cat = new apiProductCategories();
                dept.ID = p.DepartmentID;
                dept.Name = p.DepartmentName;
                cat.ID = p.CategoryID;
                cat.Name = p.CategoryName;
                p.Department = dept;
                p.Category = cat;
            }
```

Then we get the properly formatted response:

```
{
    "id": PRODUCT ID,
    "name": "PRODUCT NAME",
    "manufacturer": "PRODUCT MANUFACTURER",
    "sku": "PRODUCT SKU",
    "ean": "PRODUCT EAN",
    "department": {
        "id": DEPARTMENT ID,
        "name": "DEPARTMENT NAME"
    },
    "category": {
        "id": CATEGORY ID,
        "name": "CATEGORY NAME"
    },
    "price": PRICE,
    "msrp": MSRP,
    "inactive": false,
    "stock": STOCK,
    "weight": WEIGHT,
    "imgFull": "IMAGE LINK",
    "extendedDescription": "EXTENDED DESC"
}
```

Much neater!